# How does one retrieve and collect base-64 data-urls from the files-property of a multiple file input type?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, base64, filereader, data-uri

I am working on a front end project where I want to store only 2 images, previousImage and nextImage, and show them on a div called previousWeek and nextWeek respectively.

I am using

```
// retrieve file input
document.querySelector("#input-image").addEventListener("change", function () {
  // as localstorage only supports storing strings,
  // we have to convert our image to a datURL
  const reader=new FileReader();

  reader.addEventListener("load",() => {
    // localStorage.setItem("previous-image",reader.result);
    console.log(reader.result);
  });

  for(var i=0;i<2;i++) {
    reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[i]);    
  }
  // reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
  // console.log(this.files);
});

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const recentImageDataURL = localStorage.getItem("recent-image");
  if (recentImageDataURL) {
    document.querySelector("#previousImage").setAttribute("src", recentImageDataURL);
  }
});
```

to take input and show it previousImage div

How can I do the same, but store the next input in local storage as 'next-image'?

**What I've tried**

Using another readAsDataUrl for the next input in the `this.files` using

```
reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[1]);
```

then setting item in localstorage using

```
localStorage.setItem("next-image",reader.result);
```

That gives me the error

`script.js:30 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'readAsDataURL' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'.`

TLDR: I want to store only 2 images in local storage, and i only have 1 input html element

`<input type='file' accept='image/*' id="input-image">`

from which I'm reading both images

Comment: There is no point in storing that kind of URL in `localStorage`, since that URL would become invalid on reload.

Comment: @gre_gor would you suggest IndexedDB? I have to store images in the browser.

Comment: @PeterSeliger, nope, will close this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP's problem is due to the [`FileReader`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) instance's method [`readAsDataURL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL).

This process is blocking and can not be used on a reader instance by continuously plainly invoking it without triggering errors.

Thus one either looks for a promised based solution or as for the OP's event based approach one turns the reader's `load` handler into a function which manages both the continuous collection of base 64 image sources and its final local storage once all image data has been captured.

```js
function storeBase64ImageSourcesLocally([ recent, next ]) {
  const storageData = JSON
    .stringify({ recent, next });

  console.log({ recent, next, storageData });

  // localStorage
  //   .setItem('base-64-image-sources', storageData);
}

function proceedWithReadFileAsDataURL(reader, files) {
  if (files.length >= 1) {
    reader
      .readAsDataURL(files.shift());
  }
} 

function collectBase64ImageSourceFromBoundData() {
  const { reader, sources: { files, images } } = this;
  const base64ImageSource = reader.result;

  images
    .push(base64ImageSource);

  console.log({ images });

  if (images.length >= 2) {
    storeBase64ImageSourcesLocally(images);
  }

  // continue with the `readAsDataURL` process
  // which is blocking and can not just be invoked
  // continuously on `reader` one after the other.
  proceedWithReadFileAsDataURL(reader, files);
}
function collectAndStoreBase64ImageData({ currentTarget }) {
  let { files } = currentTarget;

  // just in case of minimum two selected files.
  if (files?.length >= 2) {

    files = [...files]
      // limit the iterable files to just 2.
      .slice(0, 2);

    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader
      .addEventListener(
        'load',
        collectBase64ImageSourceFromBoundData
          .bind({ reader, sources: { files, images: [] } }),
      );

    // initially trigger the `readAsDataURL` process
    // which is blocking and can not just be invoked
    // continuously on `reader` one after the other.
    proceedWithReadFileAsDataURL(reader, files);
  }
}

document
  .querySelector('#input-image')
  .addEventListener('change', collectAndStoreBase64ImageData);
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
label > span { display: block; margin: 0 0 6px 0; }
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 70%!important; top: auto; }
```

```html
<label>
  <span>Feel encouraged to select at least 2 image files ...</span>

  <input type="file" multiple accept="image/*" id="input-image" />
</label>
```

Answer (score -1):

maybe with [URL.createObjectURL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) but maybe with [FileSystem](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/showOpenFilePicker) is more easy to understand

```
document.querySelector("#input-image").addEventListener("change", ({ files }) => {
  const urls = files.map((file) => URL.createObjectURL(file))
  localStorage.setItem("previous-image", JSON.stringify(urls))
}
```

Comment: Did you test this code?